# Ubuntu 16.04 slow boot time problem

Tags: boot, 16.04, dmesg

Ubuntu used to boot fast but now takes too long. I don't know what's causing the problem, I've read that it might have something to do with /etc/fstab and the swap files. I ran dmesg and here is what i get: http://pastebin.com/DVVBBe5b
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: show us the result of `systemd-analyze blame`

Comment: Here's the output of systemd-anayze blame http://pastebin.com/f3rBVj4e

Comment: I don't notice anything wrong there. How long did it take to boot earlier, and how long it takes now?

Comment: From pushing the physical power button to getting to the ubuntu log in screen it takes 1 minute and 40 seconds.